# Can't install any version of Linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

So I was trying to install #! (Crunchbang) and downloaded the 64 bit version and tried installing it. Everything would work until it was time to install grub. The grub installation would fail every time.

I then tried installing the 32bit version (note I am on a 64 bit machine) and everything would install including the grub. I would then

- Start Computer
- Press <kbd>F9</kbd> (I have legacy boot enabled)

I then see these options:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/7DPX0ER.jpg]

**Note:** I do **not** have Ubuntu installed. And that these options would show even before I had #! installed.

There was no option to load #! even thought the grub had apparently installed.

When I'd select the Ubuntu options I would get:

[image: i.imgur.com/Xjf3qqS.jpg]

That error, and would have to power off my computer and turn it on to get out of that screen.

After this I downloaded EasyBCD and tried removing Ubuntu from the boot menu but there would be no Ubuntu options, it would just be these.

[image: gyazo.com/45325ec57f0c69e31af1559bb9d3cca8.png]

I then went to CMD and typed

> bcdedit

And this information came up (note I'm trying to provide as much information as I can.

[image: gyazo.com/94fcf2e09dfa5c6bbda0a642afdd0dca.png]

Lastly I tried installing a different OS (Manjaro) and when I started it up I got

[image: i.imgur.com/ntcjVdL.jpg]

**Some information about my PC and things you should know**

- Windows 8
- Intel i3, 6GB RAM, 750 HDD
- Partitions look like this right now:

  [image]
- I currently have nothing linux related installed but the Ubuntu still shows in the boot loader.
- I had Ubuntu a long time ago, don't know why it's still there.

EDIT: I am now getting the grub error an any Linux version I try, I just tried Ubuntu.

Comment: please upload your pics in the futures...

Comment: I can't because I don't have enough reputation to post pictures or more than 2 links.

Comment: If the list of partitions is complete, then I'm failing to see your Linux partition. It wouldn't seem to be that surprising that GRUB has problems finding it...

Comment: How exactly are you installing? Do you have a second hard drive? As peterph points out, there is no Linux partition in what you posted. Could you boot into a live Linux session and post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` or, if you have a GPT partition table, `sudo gdisk -l`?

Comment: I'm installing via USB. No. And that's the problem, I can't install Linux. When I try doing a live session I get the error show in the pic.